# Android Volley slow internet issue

Tags: android, android-volley

Hi I am using Volley for Networking in Android , Everything is working fine the problem is on Slow Internet Error , where time out happens but request sent to server some time it is getting processed . Can someone help me out , Even i tried increasing timeout but nothing is helpful.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011279/android-volley-checking-internet-state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration

Comment: Hi Ankita Thanks for your suggestion , i can able to catch that Slow Internet
 issue but problem is sometime it is being sent to server and processed.Consider in case of signup , i am showing slow internet connection but user is added in database.

Comment: @Shanmugam did you add `TimeoutError ` ?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya i added , when internet is slow request is sent to server , any way to block it?

Comment: @Shanmugam if `TimeoutError ` coming then you can exit task easily

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya Thanks...

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya i solved my increasing Time out duration..

Answer (score 2):

```
      @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
   String message = null;
   if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
         message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
   } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
         message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
   } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
         message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
   } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
         message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
   } else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
         message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
   } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
         message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is able to write in the server database then you may get a response even after a timeout. Please put Logs in both onResposne and in onErrorResponse methods.

```
JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
    });
```