# how to cancel volley request if there is no response in 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-volley

i want to cancel volley request if there is no response in specific time

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, test_check_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("resultarray");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("test_id","");
            map.put("chap_id","");]
            map.put("type","check_test");
            return map;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setTag(TAG);
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

i tried doing this:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getRequestQueue() != null) {
                MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getRequestQueue().cancelAll(TAG);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Request failed"+TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 10000);
```

i want to show a toast and cancel my request if there no response in 10 seconds
how can i do this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: instead of this i suggest you to define timeout..it will automatically fail the request after 10 second

Comment: You might want to set a timeout for your request, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set timeout to your request.

after that particular timeout your request will be failed and you can catch that exception inside your `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` and here you can show Toast

in your case here is the example

```
 stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(MY_TIMEOUT_MS,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
 MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

set `MY_TIMEOUT_MS` to 10000 milliseconds and `DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES` to 0

now after 10 seconds the request will be failed and inside your `ErrorResponse` you can catch it like this and show Toast

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError||error instanceof NetworkError) {
        Toast.makeText(context,context.getString(R.string.error_network_timeout),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}
```

Comment: if the internet connection is off then it doesnt work. what can be donr in such condition?@SergeyGlotov

Comment: it doesnt trigger volley error when there is no internet connection

Comment: here you can get all error..it's a different question then what you asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011279/android-volley-checking-internet-state

Comment: if connection is off it not even triggering error. error.printStackTrace(); is also not working

Comment: please consider asking this as a separate problem, if  your `onErrorResponse` not working on internet off then this problem is beyond what you asked..sometime the error can be null so check `if(error==null){System.out.println("error is null");}`